# grammar help. "how you find it ...?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, sentence-construction

your friend sent you a picture of her holding a baby porcupine to her chest. you are not a fan of little creatures. how do you comment on her picture? can you say : - "i cant imagine myself holding these little creatures. how u find these spiky animals cute, so cute that u dont mind carrying them to ur chest? me ... no. i juz cant! "

i want to know if there is any grammar mistakes in my comment? in this case is it okay to say "how you find .... "? or should i say "how do you find ... ?". or "how can you find ... ? which one fits best?

Comment: “How can you…” is what you want.

Comment: 'Text speak' isn't grammatical anyway - also, all sentences should start with a capital letter.

Comment: Please correct your punctuation. The pronoun I is capitalized. can't takes an apostrophe. The correct grammar is: **How did you find it?**

Comment: Is this a wind-up? How can you ask about "correct" use of English while using words like ***u** = you, **juz** = just* (plus numerous spelling and punctuation mistakes)? You gotta make *some* effort!

Comment: Texting has a set of acceptable lexical rules just like certain dialects do. Slang "incorrect" spelling is acceptable. The question asks about grammar, not spelling.

Comment: Text speak lines are not appropriate for submission to this site for discussion about grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Native English speakers, especially young people, commonly use "u" in place of "you," and this is acceptable for informal text communication between friends. You don't have to capitalize letters over text; it is a personal preference. It is known that some people choose to avoid capitalization to come off as more calm and less serious. However, on sites like this, you should capitalize the first letter of sentences, and always capitalize "I" even over text, in my opinion, even though some native speakers don't.

> "i cant imagine myself holding these little creatures. how u find
> these spiky animals cute, so cute that u dont mind carrying them to ur
> chest? me ... no. i juz cant!"

This is wrong. Here is what you are looking for:

> "i cant imagine myself holding these little creatures. how do u find
> these spiky animals cute, so cute that u dont mind carrying them to ur
> chest? me ... no. i juz cant!"

"How you find" is incorrect, and both "how do you find" and "how can you find" are correct in the sentence.

A way to make "how you find" correct would be to modify the sentence as follows:

> "i cant imagine myself holding these little creatures. how u find
> these spiky animals cute, so cute that u dont mind carrying them to ur
> chest, is beyond me. me ... no. i juz cant!"